# Trying to redirect in script

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, sh

I'm trying to redirect results of zgrep into a directory using shell script. But, I'm a getting the following error. 
line 7: /home/johnm/http_files/: Is a directory

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=/data/log/2015/09
for file in $FILES
do
echo "processing $file"
zgrep 'sans' $file > /home/johnm/http_files/
done
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to redirect to the file not the directory. Add some file name after the path and it should work OK.

Comment: Thank you but now i'm getting No such file or directory like so:  line 7: /home/johnm/http_files/data/log/2015/month_09: No such file or directory

Comment: Are all directories present in this path? Can you for example 'cat' this file?

Comment: Thanks. I'll refer my new issue in a different thread and mark this one as answered.